# How to install gvim on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ubuntu, gvim

I checked under Software Center, but I could not find it. How can I install gvim?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

Comment: There is two packages that seems to be good candidates vim-gnome and  vim-gtk, however I don't know how they diff.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33260/difference-between-vim-gtk-and-vim-gnome