# gvim on Lubuntu

Tags: vim, gvim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install gvim on Ubuntu 10.10?](https://superuser.com/questions/236711/how-to-install-gvim-on-ubuntu-10-10)

I can't seem to use gvim on lubuntu. After installing vim with

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

I cannot seem to start it:

```
$ gvim
The program 'gvim' can be found in the following packages:
* vim
* vim-gnome
* vim-tiny
* vim-athena
* vim-gtk
* vim-nox
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
$
```

Is this an issue with lubuntu? Is there a workaround? Vim does start in terminal mode, I would prefer gvim though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to install **vim-gtk** to get *gvim*, or **vim-gnome**  (but I prefer the -gtk one)